# lodash filter match if property value contains "x"

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

If I have an array of objects like so:

```
const array = [
{name: "Jim", attributes: "strong, handsome, tall", age: 28},
{name: "Alice", attributes: "blonde, thin, tall", age: 26},
{name: "Bob", attributes: "lazy, small, thin", age: 32}
]
```

Is there a way to use `_.filter(array)` to create a new array with objects whereby a property contains a value.
Something like _.filter(array, attributes.contains("tall")) would return desired result of:

```
[
{name: "Jim", attributes: "strong, handsome, tall", age: 28},
{name: "Alice", attributes: "blonde, thin, tall", age: 26}
]
```

Comment: Yes, there is--is there a specific issue [the docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#filter) haven't resolved?

Comment: Why do you need `lodash` for this...?

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm pretty new, but I couldn't find it in the docs. I'm really sorry if this has an obvious answer...

Comment: @DaveNewton Doesn't seem like lodash provides some sort of way to describe "string includes substring".

Comment: @vsync largely because I've been using lodash to make things more readable up till now, and how it would be done without lodash - to my green mind - requires a lot of lines of code. I figured lodash would offer a simple path...

Comment: @caTS It doesn't need to; for everything other than shorthand it takes a function.

Comment: Well then native `filter` can do that already :p

Comment: @JosephWalsh See [MDN Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this vanilla JS.

try the [filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), but please note it is a shallow copy - so if you update the original array, your filter will be different also.

```js
array.filter(el => el.attributes.includes('tall'))
```

This is possible because the String type has the [`includes` method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp).

Updated to use includes instead of contains. both work.

Comment: I believe this is not what OP really meant. There is a list of words in `attributes` and should make sure the query is a complete word and not a part of a word.

Comment: `contains` is not a string/array method in javascript ;)

Comment: Also, you did no change which is related to my first comment, what so ever. You misunderstood me I assume. You need to match whole words either via regex or by splitting the string and matching only then use the `includes` method (on the Array)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with the built-in [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and checking if the attributes of the person includes `"tall"`.

```js
const array = [
{name: "Jim", attributes: "strong, handsome, tall", age: 28},
{name: "Alice", attributes: "blonde, thin, tall", age: 26},
{name: "Bob", attributes: "lazy, small, thin", age: 32}
];

const tallPeople = array.filter(
  (person) => person.attributes.includes("tall")
);

console.log(tallPeople);
```